# Why is the third level not showing in my superfish menu?

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm having a super fish menu wih three layers of menu points but my second layer links do not seem to be expanding even tho "Show as expanded" is checked for the individual menu points (2nd level) that is selected as "Parent item" for the 3rd level page.

Some links:
menu point with submenus: http://www.lslib.ca/content/skwlax-daycare
Third level page(hidden from the menu): http://www.lslib.ca/content/admin

How can I get the third level to display?

**EDIT 1**

I don't exaxctly know how Superfish binds into the configration either. 
Maybe a link to the page would help: http://www.lslib.ca/
Under Blocks, I only see Content assigned to a Region. I'm officially confused here... :o

**EDIT 2**

The name of the theme is `Nexus Theme`, under `admin/appearance` it says: `Nexus Theme is a premium Drupal 7 theme. Developed by Devsaran.com.`

In `page.tpl.php` I have the following:

```
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
  <div id="main-menu">
    <?php 
      if (module_exists('i18n_menu')) {
        $main_menu_tree = i18n_menu_translated_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
      } else {
        $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
      }
      print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
    ?>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is this still an open question? Did you finish formulating it (it seems unfinished)? Which are the menu points that are not expanding in your example pages?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis hoops, yes I properly finished the sentence now. Yes, it still is a problem,  the menu extension should be: `Departments » Skwlax Daycare » Admin`

Comment: Did you fix it? I can see the "Admin" option at the moment.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis no, I can't what browser? I'm using Chromium Version 49.0.2623.87 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Comment: Windows NT 10.0
Firefox / 45.0

Comment: Yep, Firefox works for me too (Linux) but Chrome & Chromium won't

Comment: Any luck with this one? Did you try the suggestion below?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis see below

Comment: Which theme are you using? Confusion is Drupal's middle name ;)

Comment: Please see **EDIT 2** above

Comment: Could you check your browser's console for any JavaScript errors and post them?

Comment: You can also check the "Update:" section in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give this a try:

> In the drupal bloc configuration just disable "Slide-in effect"

Quoting the last comment from this thread:
https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish/issues/30

Hope you get lucky with this, that whole github thread could be also interesting/relevant to your issue.

Update: This is apparently a theme specific superfish implementation, the respective theme being (most probably) [Nexus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nexus)

In order to deactive the effects that could be causing the error, you should edit the file sites/all/themes/nexus/js/custom.js at about line 7, commenting out the animation options:

```
//  animation:   { opacity:'show',height:'show'},   // fade-in and slide-down animation
```

Hope this does the trick!

Comment: thanks for the link & the help but I have not been able to get it to work yet. I set all 4  block entries to `Slide-in effect` `- None -` but it still does nbot extend in Chrome - however, I also have to say that none of the blocs are actually assigned to a region. I'm a little confused here, all superfish blocks have the Region set to `- None -`

Comment: Where does superfish bind into your configuration? Is is part of a specific theme you are using?

Comment: Please see **EDIT 1** above

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the update: section in the answer? Did it work? Very curious about this...

Comment: BANG! That was it (the **update**) I hadn't actually seen it! Great, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fantastic! Very welcome!